# Pandas Drop Row if there's only one occurrence of a value

Tags: pandas, dataframe, duplicates

Say that we have the pandas table:

```
+-------+-------------------+
| Name  |       Dog         |
+-------+-------------------+
| Alice | husky             | 
| Bob   | husky             | 
| Chris | pom               | 
| Ferri | malamute          | 
| Bob2  | corgi             | 
| Dave2 | corgi             |
+-------+-------------------+
```

How do we remove the rows that only have one-entry for "Dog"? For example, this would be the rows with pom, malamute.

```
+-------+-------------------+
| Name  |       Dog         |
+-------+-------------------+
| Alice | husky             | 
| Bob   | husky             | 
| Bob2  | corgi             | 
| Dave2 | corgi             |
+-------+-------------------+
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
is_multi = df["Dog"].value_counts() > 1
filtered = df[df["Dog"].isin(is_multi[is_multi].index)]
```